# Playframework: update / delete mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, jpa, playframework

Right now Play! automatically adds new tables to my mySQL database if I manually delete them. I remember reading a while back that it was possible to make play update the tables (without me needing to delete them first) when the models are changed.

I wasn't able to find anything with google, does anyone know how I can activate this? My biggest problems are the constraints that JPA is adding, they make it quite difficult do delete tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way hibernate/play manages the database on Model changes is via the **jpa.ddl** property in your application.conf. If you read the file it states.

```
# Specify the ddl generation pattern to use. Set to none to disable it
# (default to update in DEV mode, and none in PROD mode):
# jpa.ddl=update
```

The options that I know about are

- `jpa.ddl=update`   - This simply updates the tables when a model changes
- `jpa.ddl=create-drop`   - This deletes the tables and recreates on model changes
- jpa.ddl=validate -Just checks the schema, but does not make any changes
- jpa.ddl=none - Does nothing

You can read more about this on the [Hibernate site](http://docs.jboss.org/modeshape/latest/manuals/reference/html/jdbc-storage-connector.html) under the first property `autoGenerateSchema`

Comment: On the link you posted it says that this happens when  EntityManagerFactory is opend and closed. Any idea at what point this happens in Play? I'm not getting any results by simply refreshing the page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: According to the Play doc, it says `Play will automatically start the Hibernate entity manager when it finds one or more classes annotated with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation`